# Validating email format in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to create a simple registration page in Django and to check all fields validation. I tried to check the email field format validation but I could not find any source to do that.
Can you help me please?

Here is the view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, request
from django.db import connection
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import pyodbc

def newUser(request):  
     form = NewUserFrom(request.POST or None)
     if not form.is_valid():     
          context = {'frmNewUser':form}
          return render(request,'login/newuser.html', context)
     return render(request, "login/welcome.html")
```

Here is the forms.py:

```
from ctypes import alignment
from email import message
from urllib import request
from django import forms

class NewUserFrom(forms.Form):
    error_css_class = 'error'
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput, label="Username")
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="Password")
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(label="Confirm password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput, label="Name")
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50, widget=forms.EmailInput, label="Email")

    def clean_password(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        pwd = cleaned_data.get('password')
        cof_pwd = cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')
        # if pwd and cof_pwd:
        if pwd != cof_pwd:      
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password is not match.')
        return cleaned_data
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(NewUserFrom,self).clean()
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email.strip() == "".strip():
            # self.add_error('email','Email is reqiered.')
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email is reqiered.')
        else: 
            fistPart, secPart = str(email).split('@')
            
        raise forms.ValidationError('Email error.')
```

Here is the NewUser.html:

```
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{frmNewUser.as_table}}
        {% for field in frmNewUser.fields %}
            {% if field.errors %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p style="color: red;">{{error}}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" colspan=2>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: what do you mean by validating email? because in your forms, EmailField will validate user email automatically.

Comment: I mean to enter a valid email in the email field. For example, if you entered "xyz@email", this is a wrong email format. Another example, is to enter "xyz" this is also a wrong email format. The last example is to leave the email textbox blank.

Comment: OK. all the things you said is done by EmailField automatically in your forms, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: maybe you mean the browser validation. I wanna do my custom validation to show my message.

Answer (score 1):

It is always safer and recommended to use the build-in email validator that comes with Django.

You have not put blank=True and null=True while declaring email. So, Django will always make sure that this field is never blank/null. Django will also make sure that only valid email address is entered by user. As a matter of fact, you need not do anything else.

```
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50, widget=forms.EmailInput, label="Email")
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.clean

Comment: I need to create my custom validation message. How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to modify email address in Django forms**

```
email_user_part_regex = re.compile(
    r"^(?=.{4,30}$)[\w\u0080-\uffff]+(?:[\.\-+][\w\u0080-\uffff]+)*$",
    re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE,
)
```

class ForgetPasswordEmailForm(forms.Form):

```
email = forms.EmailField(label='email', max_length=200)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    validate_email.user_regex = email_user_part_regex
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?